# Duplicate / clone mysql database on RDS from a shell script on EC2

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, amazon-rds

I have a database called 'X' on RDS.

I have an EC2 instance where I wish to run a .sh script that would do following:

- Connect to the said RDS Instance
- Create database 'Y' (drop if exists) on same RDS instance
- Copy all data from 'x' to 'Y'

I have installed mysql-client on EC2 and tried out following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
PRODUCTION_DB=X
COPY_DB=Y
ERROR=~/mysql_dump_error.log
mysql -h xxxx.rds.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -u xxxx --password=xxxx -e "drop database if exists $COPY_DB;" --force && mysql -h xxxx.rds.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -u xxxx --password=xxxx -e "create database $COPY_DB;" && mysqldump --force --log-error=$ERROR -h xxxx.rds.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -u xxxx --password=xxxx $PRODUCTION_DB | mysql -h xxxx.rds.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -u xxxx --password=xxxx $COPY_DB
```

Thanks to https://www.harecoded.com/copycloneduplicate-mysql-database-script-2184438/

Dropping & creating new DB works fine but during mysql dump, I get following error:

```
Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation
```

How do I go about adding privilege to my use? Is it the right thing to do? Or I should find some another way?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: Thanks @Cyrus, I have updated my question accordingly.